# Virtual Machine Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, domain, virtual-machines

I have a VM with Win2k3 x64 Enterprise Edition installed. I have DNS Server and AD(DC) Server roles added to this VM. I would like to know if I could join my laptop (which is the host for the VM) to the domain I created on the VM. When I try to change the domain of my laptop to the domain I created on the VM I get the following error:

> The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
>   (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

I feel I am missing some steps/configurations. What is the best way to do this? Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Move your question to "Server Fault". You can try to make the DNS entry of your host computer to point on your VM DNS, but not sure of the result. According to me you'd better forget this architecture.

Comment: What are the network settings of your host and your DC vm?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* howerver you're going to have issues with authentication and logging in since the VM won't be up until after you log in and start VMWare.

What you are probably missing is that you need to set your DNS server to the IP of the VM so that is can look up the DC location